# Maximum dataset size for Chart.js

Tags: browser, chart.js

I've got a hidden field that contains the values of dataset. Whith Chart.js I read the hidden field and then I plot the graph.

I've got 2 questions:

1. Which is the maximum number of values that a scatter graph can display?
2. Consider a dataset with thousands values (> 100.000) that can't be rendered with one load becouse dataset is too big to be stored in a hidden field. Is there a way to fragment the dataset in part and render only if user demand it (like a scrollbar and load the first half by default and if moved to load the second half)?